Is it true that the letter I is pronounced as a consonant when it's the first letter of a syllable?
I am asking specifically for traditional central European pronunciation. I have only seen one source claiming this so I am not sure

By "central European", are you referring to Medieval Latin then? Otherwise, the topic of consonantal I has been covered here and here in great detail.

One wonders how you think the word "in" is pronounced …

The short answer is no. Sometimes (usually) an I before a vowel is a consonant, and sometimes (seldom) it's a vowel. You have to learn it for each individual word.
This is one reason why it's good to use the letter J when it's a consonant: so you can tell the difference at a glance.
